React-native-bootom-sheet animated handle height
I am using react-native-bottom-sheet together with the bottomsheetview and the botttomsheetscrollview in my react-native app. I have three snap points, one at the bottom of the screen, one in the middle and one at the top. I only want the handle component of the bottom sheet to be visible at the bottom snap point. To achieve this, I am using an animated view and the animatedPosition prop of the bottom sheet. I then interpolate the opacity and height of the handle component.
The opacity animation works perfectly. However, animating the height of the handle is buggy, e.g. the handle appears and disappears unpredictably.
Does anyone know a fix for the animated handle height or can suggest another way to achieve the desired goal of only seeing the handle at the bottom snap point (and having a smooth transition).
Here is the animated handle style:
  const animatedTextStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const height = interpolate(
      translateY.value,
      [SNAP_TOP, SNAP_MIDDLE, SNAP_BOTTOM],
      [blurViewHeight, 6, 50],
      Extrapolation.CLAMP
    );

    const opacity = interpolate(
      translateY.value,
      [SNAP_TOP, SNAP_MIDDLE, SNAP_BOTTOM],
      [0, 0, 1], 
      Extrapolation.CLAMP
    );

    return {
      opacity,
      height,
    };
  });

And here is the handle component:
 handleComponent={() => (
            <Animated.View
              style={[
                {
                  width: "100%",
                },
                animatedTextStyle,
              ]}
            >
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  width: "100%",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
                disabled={rooms.length === 0}
                onPress={() => {
                  bottomSheetRef.current?.snapToIndex(1);
                }}
              >
                <View
                  style={{
                    width: 40,
                    height: 5,
                    backgroundColor: secondTextColor,
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    marginTop: 10,
                    marginBottom: 2,
                  }}
                />
                <ThemedText muted={true} type="defaultSemiBold">
                  {rooms.length}{" "}
                  {rooms.length > 1 || rooms.length === 0
                    ? "results"
                    : "result"}
                </ThemedText>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
          )}


It might help to pull your component out of inline and define it either outside the scope of your sheet component or at least in a usecallback.

Thanks! I settled on not animating the height. You can achieve something very similar by using a fixed height for the handle and translating the content of the bottom sheet over it.

I will leave this question open in case someone has a precise explanation for the problem. Maybe animating the height somehow interferes with calculating the y-positioning of the modal?
